# When to use cte and temp table?

Tags: common-table-expression, temp-tables

i know this a common question, but most frequently people ask about performancy between this two. 
What I'm asking for is use cases of cte and temp table, for better understanding the usage of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a temp table you can use `CONSTRAINT's` and `INDEX's`. You can also create a `CURSOR` on a temp table where a CTE terminates after the **end of the query**(emphasizing a single query).

I will answer through specific use cases with an application I've had experience with in order to aid with my point.

**Common use cases in an example enterprise application I've used is as follows:**

---

**Temp Tables**

Normally, we use temp tables in order to transform data before `INSERT` or `UPDATE` in the appropriate tables in time that require **more than one query**.  Gather similar data from multiple tables in order to manipulate and process the data.

There are different types of orders (order_type1, order_type2, order_type3) all of which are on different `TABLE's` but have similar `COLUMN's`.  We have a `STORED PROCEDURE` that `UNION's` all these tables into one `#orders` temp table and `UPDATE's` a persons suggested orders depending on existing orders.

**CTE's**

CTE's are awesome for **readability** when dealing with single queries.  When creating reports that requires analysis using `PIVOT's`,`Aggregates`, etc. with tons of lines of code, CTE's provide readability by being able to separate a huge query into logical sections.

---

Sometimes there is a combination of both.  When **more than one query** is required. Its still useful to break down some of those queries with CTE's.

I hope this is of some usefulness, cheers!